# Problem/Answer Counter

Tags: numbering

I'm writing solutions to some problems in lecture notes and have run into the issue of problem and answer counters not being synchronized. Here's what I mean:

[image]

To get around this issue (of it saying Answer 1.2 rather than 1.3), I've just added the extra line

```
\setcounter{answer}{2}
```

, but this is somewhat burdensome when I rearrange problems and have to manually set many answer numberings. Is there a solution to this? For reference, here is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Problem,numberwithin=section]{prob}
\declaretheorem[name=Answer,numberwithin=section]{answer}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{trivlist}\item[]{\textbf{Solution.}}}{\qed \end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}

\begin{prob}
Problem text.
\end{prob}

\begin{answer}
Answer.
\end{answer}

\begin{solution}
Solution text.
\end{solution}

\begin{prob}
This is a proof problem.
\end{prob}

\begin{proof}
Proof text.
\end{proof}

\begin{prob}
Problem text.
\end{prob}

\begin{answer}
Oh no, the answer numbering is bad.
\end{answer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you have a separate counter for answers? If they always follow the problem why can't it simply use the same counter (and not change it)

Comment: Then it would have Problem 1.1, then Answer 1.2, then Problem 1.3, then Problem 1.4, then Answer 1.5, no?

Comment: Could you post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to show how you make these problem/answer environments?

Comment: No just use the problem number don't increment it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `amsthm`'s environments, but defining other environments from them to adjust the counters when problems and answers are called.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\newtheorem{ans}{Answer}
\numberwithin{prob}{section}
\numberwithin{ans}{section}
\newenvironment{problem}{%
    \addtocounter{ans}{1}
    \begin{prob}
    }{%
    \end{prob}
}
\newenvironment{answer}{%
    \addtocounter{ans}{-1}
    \begin{ans}
    }{%
    \end{ans}
}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{problem}
Problem text.
\end{problem}
\begin{answer}
Answer.
\end{answer}
\begin{problem}
Proof problem without answer.
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
Problem text.
\end{problem}
\begin{answer}
Yeah, the answer number is right!
\end{answer}
\end{document}
```